# How can I use the OUT parameter from a SQL Server stored procedure in a vb.net code

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, out-parameters

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that takes an `IN` parameter and an `OUT` parameter:

```
create PROCEDURE  [dbo].[GetServiceByKeyword] @keyword nvarchar(30), @Service INT OUT 
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @service = Service 
    from Keyword_Service 
    where Keyword = @keyword 
END
```

I'm calling it in **vb.net** like this:

```
If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

cm = New SqlCommand("dbo.getservicebykeyword", cn)
cm.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyword", id)

Dim Srvce As New SqlParameter("@Service", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
Srvce.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Output
cm.Parameters.Add(Srvce)
```

How can I use the output from this stored procedure? (`Srvce`)

Its the first time I use OUT parameters and I wanna transform the result to String to be able to use it in the code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Call your proc and then access `Srvce.Value` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after calling cm.Execute(), you can get the value using:

```
dim result=cm.Parameters("@Service").Value
```

hope it will help you

regards